# C Programming - Printing Hexedecimal Character Whose Most Significant Bit is 1

Tags: c, hex

The code snippet

```
char c1;
char c2;
c1 = 0X7F;
c2 = 0X80;
printf("c1 = %X\nc2 = %X\n", c1, c2);
```

outputs

```
c1 = 7F
c2 = FFFFFF80
```

why is it that `c2` does not print as `80`? (i'm guessing it's something to do with the fact that the most significant bit of 0X80 is 1 while the MSB of 0x7F is 0). how can i get `c2` to print as simply `80`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `printf` is a *variadic function*.  Arguments to variadic functions undergo the *default promotions*; one effect of this is that `char` arguments are converted to `int`.  On your platform, `char` is `signed`, so `c2` is actually negative.  `printf` is therefore printing all the leading ones that occur in the `int` (these are due to two's-complement representation).

There are (at least) 3 methods to work around this:

- <s>Use `%02X` rather than `%X` as your `printf` format specifier.</s>
- Use `unsigned char` rather than `char` (this gets promoted to `unsigned int`, so no leading ones)
- Explicitly convert each of your `char`s to `int`, and then mask: `(int)c2 & 0xFF`.

[*Note: The corollary of this is that the behaviour of `char c2 = 0x80` is actually implementation-defined; if `char` is `signed` then this will overflow.*]

Comment: Normally, an `int` can hold all values of an `unsigned char`, so it would still be promoted to `int`. But since then `0x80` is positive, sign-extension doesn't introduce `1`s.

Comment: thanks, `unsigned char` works. just to let you know that using `%02X` still results in the same thing though.

Answer (score 2):

`c2` gets (sign-)extended to `int`. The following will do what you require:

```
printf("c1 = %X\nc2 = %X\n", c1, ((int)c2) & 0xFF);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `unsigned char` to print as per your need. Here is a [ideone sample](http://www.ideone.com/HVEGn)

```
unsigned char c1;
unsigned char c2;
c1 = 0X7F;
c2 = 0X80;
printf("c1 = %X\nc2 = %X\n", c1, c2);
```

As mentioned already the output you are seeing is due to sign extension.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

in order to force printf to treat that as a character, you need to give the "hh" modifier.  try:

```
printf("c1 = %hhX\nc2 = %hhX\n", c1, c2);
```

Comment: thanks, i knew that using the "h" modifier gets the variable treated as a short (2-bytes). didn't know that using "hh" gets it treated as a single byte.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing `char`s and having them read as `unsigned int`s, you're lucky it works at all.  That said, `char` is signed.  0x80 actually makes it negative.  They are apparently being converted to ints and then unsigned.  That extends the sign bit, thence the `f`s.